# MongoDB setIntesection on array of arrays

Tags: mongodb

I'm pretty new to Mongo DB, and I'm having a bit of trouble getting the aggregate intersection working.

Let's say I only have the following document in a collection:

```
{"ids" : [ [ 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 ], [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 ], [1, 3, 5, 7] ] }
```

and I would like to return

```
{"intersection" : [1, 7]}
```

I'm doing:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {$project: {intersection:{$setIntersection:"$ids"}}} ])
```

but that is returning

```
{"intersection" : [ [ 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 ], [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 ], [1, 3, 5, 7] ] }
```

I'm assuming it is because "$ids" is interpreted as an array of an array of ints, as opposed to var-args where each arg is an array of ints.

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: you want to return [1, 7] - what does that represent?  elements that occur in each of the subarrays?

Comment: Yep, the intersection of all the subarrays.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to find all elements that occur in every array inside of ids.

This can't be handled with set intersection because these are array elements and not fields in a document and there isn't a way to refer to individual array elements in projections.

Here is a work-around for you, may or may not work, depending on the rest of the aggregation needs:

```
db.inter.aggregate(
     {$project:{ids:1,  sz:{$size:"$ids"}}},
     {$unwind:"$ids"},
     {$unwind:"$ids"},
     {$group:{_id:{_id:"$_id",ids:"$ids"},count:{$sum:1},need:{$first:"$sz"}}},
     {$project:{keep:{$eq:["$need","$count"]}}},{$match:{keep:true}},{$sort:{_id:1}},
     {$group:{_id:"$_id._id",intersection:{$push:"$_id.ids"}}},
     {$project:{ intersection:1}}
)
```

This figures out how many elements the array of arrays has and then calculates how many times each number appears in unwound set.  If it's same as size, it must have been in each subelement.   This assumes, however, that each subelement can not have the same number twice.